# Is it idiomatic to say "to push your poo" when you mean "to try hard to push the waste out of your bowel when you are constipated"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

> [​constipated](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/constipated?q=constipated) adjective: unable to get rid of waste material from the
>   bowels easily
>
> You should eat more fibre and fruit if you are constipated.

---

Suppose that your child is constipated and is trying it hard to push the poo out of his bowel, you are watching him struggling to poo then you say:

**You are pushing your poo, aren't you?**

Is it idiomatic to say "**to push your poo**" when you mean "**to try hard to push the waste out of your bowel when you are constipated**"?

Comment: Tell me this is an April fools joke?

Comment: @swdev, it is not a joke, it is a question reflecting my real life situation.

Comment: It's a subject that most people would only talk about in private. Also, families often invent their own private ways of talking about bodily functions with small children. I think the 'official' word that a doctor would use is _straining_.

Comment: @KateBunting, when searching "strain to poo", I found a lot of terms such as "squeeze poop out", "push / pull poop out", etc. Are they acceptable in casual conversations? https://www.google.com/search?ei=qqWFXra0O6Ltz7sP87ajiAw&q=%22strain+to+poo%22&oq=%22strain+to+poo%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIICAAQBxAKEB4yCAgAEAcQChAeMggIABAHEAoQHjIICAAQBxAKEB4yCAgAEAcQChAeMgQIABANMgQIABANMgYIABANEB4yBggAEA0QHjIGCAAQDRAeOgQIABBHOgIIADoECAAQHjoGCAAQBRAeOgYIABAWEB46CAgAEBYQChAeUMnPAVjv5QFgkOgBaABwAngAgAF_iAHiApIBAzAuM5gBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi2sZDZrMnoAhWi9nMBHXPbCMEQ4dUDCAs&uact=5

Comment: As I tried to indicate, with a subject like this it's difficult to say what is or isn't 'acceptable in conversation'. When speaking to your young child you can use whatever terms you like. _Poo_ itself is really 'baby talk', though in recent years it has become an all-purpose acceptable word for excrement.

Comment: Poop is mainly American baby talk for faeces ("feces" in America). Poo seems popular these days in Britain, although I was taught to write 'pooh'. A formal or adult term is [straining at stool](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15902151)

Comment: @Tom "it is a question reflecting my real life situation." Thanks for sharing that. At least we were spared pictures.